# getline() memory reallocation fails

Tags: c, file, memory, io, getline

After successfully opening a file with `FILE * some_file("somefile.txt", "r")`, I'm using `getline()` to read a line.
I can provide `getline()` enough buffer `char * line = malloc((size_t) 1024);`, which works fine. I can also provide less buffer than needed - `char * line = malloc((sizeof(char)))` or a `NULL`-pointer `char * line = NULL;`, and, as expected, `getline()` is allocating/reallocating and modifying value of `line`.

```
char * line = malloc((sizeof(char)))
size_t n;
n = getline(&line, &n, some_file);
```

But if I declare a pointer without defining some value or buffer, I get the error ***not enough space*** (the system is not crashing!).

```
char * line ;
size_t n;
n = getline(&line, &n, some_file); // Error: Not enough space
```

Where's the difference between providing a specific buffer `char * line = malloc(sizeof(char)))` - which should be a pointer to a char (I know I'm allowed to use this memory due to `malloc()`) and `char * line;` - which should also be a pointer to a char (of course I don't know if I'm allowed to use this memory, but the program is not crashing)?

Comment: Given `size_t n;`, what's the value in `n`?  Read the [dpcumentation for `getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) carefully.

Comment: "malloc((sizeof(char)))" this will allocate exactly one byte. Are you sure? :)

Comment: Given that n is not initialized, it might contain some insanly big value, which can not be allocated.

Comment: @Devolus Of course it's 2 bytes! Thanks for reminding me, I've corrected this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the lack of initialization of variables, which leads to values not expected by `getline`. If unitialized, variables with *automatic storage duration have indeterminate values*. Using those values will lead to *undefined behaviour*.

The proper way to initialize `line` is to set it to **`NULL`** and let `getline` do the malloc it seems fit,

**or** if you already have allocated some memory that you insist you want to reuse again here, then **`n` needs to be set to the size** of the memory allocation. I.e. either:

```
char * line = malloc(1);
size_t n = 1;
ssize_t rv = getline(&line, &n, some_file);
```

OR

```
char * line = NULL
size_t n; // or can explicitly initialize this to `= 0` but it shouldn't matter
ssize_t rv = getline(&line, &n, some_file);
```

Therefore **both** excerpts in your question are **dead wrong**.

Finally, the return value is of type `ssize_t` and it has **nothing to do with `n`** except that upon return the value of that will be **strictly less** than the value stored in `n`. You must not store it in the same variable!

---

To process *each and every* line in some file with `getline` it is not necessary to call `malloc` - and just let `getline` handle the memory allocation:

```
char * line = NULL;
size_t n = 0;
while (1) {
    errno = 0;
    ssize_t rv = getline(&line, &n, some_file);
    if (rv < 0) {
        if (feof(some_file)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "end of file, no problemo.");
        }
        else if (ferror(some_file)) {
            perror("an error occurred while reading from the file");
        }
        else {
            perror("some other error occurred");
        }
        free(line);
        break;
    }

    // at this point `line` points to an array
    // of `rv` characters, with possible embedded nulls,
    // meaning one line of data from the file,
    // + the terminating null character
    //
    // `n` is the *total number* of allocated bytes in the 
    // allocation pointed to by `line`.

    printf("I got a line of input: ");
    fwrite(line, 1, rv, stdout);
}
```